# Quelle est la différence d'usage des termes « master » et « magistère » ?

Tags: usage, choix-de-mot, éducation

Sortant d'une école d'ingénieur, je me suis toujours considéré comme ayant un diplôme équivalent au grade de master, ou comme on dit également « Master's degree ».

Cependant, j'ai certains amis qui sortent de l'université, et eux parlent plutôt de magistère pour décrire leur niveau académique en France. Je ne vois pas vraiment la différence au final, mis à part le fait que le terme master est assez international.

Est-ce juste moi, ou les universitaires ont plus tendance à parler de magistère? Cela a-t-il un sens de faire la distinction aujourd'hui?

Comment: http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ma%C3%AEtrise_%28France%29, http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magist%C3%A8re_%28dipl%C3%B4me%29 que dire de plus?

Comment: @Unfrancophone Ca ne répond pas à ma question qui est de savoir l'**usage** actuel des termes, je connaissais déja les définitions théoriques des termes qui ne m'apportent pas grand chose, de plus je faisais explicitement référence à l'anglicisme master et non maitrise.

Comment: Donc [http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_(France)](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_%28France%29)

Comment: @Unfrancophone Encore une fois ca ne répond pas à ma question et c'est hors-sujet, je cherche l'usage actuel, pas la définition Wikipédia que je connais déja très bien.

Comment: Le nom des diplômes ne suivent pas un usage informel mais bien un usage formel qui va dépendre du pays, de la formation suivie et du moment où elle l'a été (et c'est pourquoi les traduire est toujours sujet à caution, même d'un pays francophone à un autre ils ne désignent pas toujours la même chose). Il ne s'agit pas d'une tendance que l'on suit ou non. Les pages de wikipedia donnent ces indications, en particulier sur l'évolution (on est souvent au courant de la signification qui s'applique à nous, pas de l'évolution antérieure ou postérieure).

Comment: Pour moi c'est surtout la tendance administrative à tout traduire, qui nous a aussi valu l'insanité qu'est « mastère ». Tant qu'au fond c'est bac+5, ben c'est un master.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Le problème tient vraiment à l'absence totale de connexion entre les diplômes américains et français sous le doctorat (du moins c'est l'impression que j'en ai quand j’entends parler des diplômes français !).

Au Québec, le « master's degree » est appelé « maîtrise », c'est le diplôme qui précède le doctorat. Je ne crois pas qu'aucun pays francophone emploie couramment « magistère » pour désigner un diplôme moderne.

Comment: C'est étonnant, je n'ai que très rarement entendu parler de maitrise, mais plus de magistère en ce qui concerne mes amis universitaires. J'imagine que cela doit dépendre des lieux également.

Comment: Après examen rapide des liens de Un Francophone, le magistère semble être en France une filière distincte du master, mais qui est relativement proche ("Le cursus consiste à suivre les cours de 3e année de licence, puis des deux années de master de la discipline correspondante mais éventuellement remaniés, ainsi que des cours supplémentaires."). La différence semble être au niveau de la formation, qui m'apparaît orientée plus professionnel qu’académique.

Answer (score 7):

Première différence, le magistère est un diplôme universitaire c'est-à-dire n'existant que dans certaines universités, tandis que le master est un diplôme national.

Deuxième différence, le master (en France en tout cas) dure deux ans : Master 1 puis Master 2 (Professionnel ou Recherche) alors que le magistère regroupe la dernière année de licence (Licence 3 ou licence dans l'ancien système) et les deux ans du master. En général, pour intégrer un magistère il faut de meilleurs résultats que pour une licence 3 classique et par ailleurs il faut suivre et donc valider des cours supplémentaires en plus des cours traditionnels de L3, M1 et M2.

En résumé :

- **Licence/Bachelor**

  - L1,L2 / Deug
  - L3 / Licence
- **Master/Post-graduate**

  - M1 / Maitrise
  - M2(P ou R) / DESS ou DEA
- **Doctorat/PhD**